# How to create WPF button that drops down a listBox

Tags: wpf, button, listbox

I'm trying to create a button in main window that would look like a globe, which would allow user to select his/her location. I want it to display a listBox when clicked on it just below the button itself.

Any hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to do this is restyle a ComboBox and then restyle the ToggleButton in the ComboBox and remove the editable textbox.

This will avoid you having the implement the functions of the ComboBox for your popup.

Try using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Another Approach would be to use the Expander Control with a list box in it
[Link](http://www.wpftutorial.net/Expander.html)

OR

You could play with the Listbox's visibility property